# Focus and click button without hiding soft keyboard

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

In a cordova App there is a "listview" element that gets populated by buttons when typing in an input field.

When one of the buttons is clicked the keyboard hides focusing on the body viewport and then you have to click second time for the button to be actually clicked.

**Is there anyway to keep the keyboard open while clicking the button?**

**UPDATE:** I tried binding event to the buttons so that when one of them is focused it gets clicked and the keyboard gets focused back. The problem is that when you click on any of them when the keyboard is open, the entire viewport gets focused, the keyboard closes and the event that I put doesn't get fired until you click second time.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try `$(INPUT).focus()`

Comment: try adding `return false;` to the end of the click handle of the buttons so the clicking doesn't propagate to the view port

Comment: @HusseinNazzal I tried and it doesn't work. It looks like that once the keyboard is open and you click regardless if its on the button or not the viewport gets focused and then you need to click again on the button.

Comment: i'm having the same problem with a plain javascript mobile application.